# CouchDB update_notification, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb

I have a nodejs application which I use as an external process for the update_notification handler of my CouchDB instance.
The nodejs application is responsible to replicate from some standard DBs into a newly created DB. The replication works somehow, but the nodejs application gets destroyed arbitrary.

This is the code how the application is listen for the notification handler

```
var stdin = process.openStdin();


stdin.setEncoding('utf8');


stdin.on('data', function(d) {
    // Parsen des Ergebnis
    if (d !== null) {
        parsedData.push(JSON.parse(d));
    }
});
```

And this is the code which handels the result from the array `parsedData`

```
var checker = function() {
    for (var index in parsedData) {
        var parsed = parsedData[index];
        if (parsed.type === "created" && parsed.db !== "design" && parsed.db !== "custom") {
            // start replication
        }
    }

    parsedData = [];

    setTimeout(checker, 1000);
};
```

This is the error log

```
** Last message in was {#Port<0.36681>,{exit_status,8}}
** When Server state == {os_proc,"nodejs /config/db_create/init_db_helper.js",
                                 #Port<0.36681>,
                                 #Fun<couch_os_process.2.14837184>,
                                 #Fun<couch_os_process.3.14837184>,5000}
** Reason for termination == 
** {exit_status,8}

[Fri, 26 Aug 2016 13:35:07 GMT] [error] [<0.9594.0>] {error_report,<0.9237.0>,
                      {<0.9594.0>,crash_report,
                       [[{initial_call,
                          {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}},
                         {pid,<0.9594.0>},
                         {registered_name,[]},
                         {error_info,
                          {exit,
                           {exit_status,8},
                           [{gen_server,terminate,6,
                             [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,744}]},
                            {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,
                             [{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,239}]}]}},
                         {ancestors,
                          [couch_db_update,couch_primary_services,
                           couch_server_sup,<0.9238.0>]},
                         {messages,[]},
                         {links,[<0.9295.0>]},
                         {dictionary,[]},
                         {trap_exit,false},
                         {status,running},
                         {heap_size,987},
                         {stack_size,27},
                         {reductions,968}],
                        []]}}
[Fri, 26 Aug 2016 13:35:07 GMT] [error] [<0.9295.0>] Update notification process <0.9594.0> died: {exit_status,
                                                                   8}
```

As I read on different sites, the external process has to be in an infinite loop. But I'm not sure if my setup is somehow infinite??

Comment: What are you doing in the "startReplication" ?

Comment: Hey, I start two different continuous replications with the node module `nano`. After that the script is doing some formatting to a design doc and at the end it uploads a security object to my new database.

Comment: If I look to the log output, the node application always crashs if something happen to a design document. Well i think i simple forgot to handle that case properly. Do you have any other tipps?